# ubuntu wont start

Tags: boot

I've been trying to fix this problem for the past 2-3 weeks without success.

I had Mint 2 weeks ago when the problem first appeared. Then I tried to reinstall Mint, but it's still not working. Now I installed Ubuntu MATE instead, but I'm still having the same problem.

I have one HD, and `/home` is on a different partition.

When I turn on the PC I reach this black screen:

```
minimal bash like line editing is supported.
```

[image: here is the photo]

I managed to temporarily pass that screen by doing:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos7)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos7)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

which leads me to:

```
you are in emergency mode. After logging in...
```

[image: here is the photo]

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in type "journalctl -xb" to view   
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"   
to boot into default mode.  
Press Enter for maintenance  
(or press Control-D to continue): _
```

I've been trying many suggestions I saw online, but I can't make it work. Does anyone have a solution before I format the entire filesystem?

Comment: If you're having the same problem with multiple operating system, either your hardware is faulty, or you're doing something way off spec. Are you following any guides to install Ubuntu?  Are you certain that you've installed the operating system properly?

Comment: livecd runs smoothly, therefore hardware is fine. Installed properly, ive installed linux many times in the past decade. I ran fsck, there were few errors, got them fixed. I followed many "solutions" online, none worked.

Comment: Where do you think the errors came from that came up during fsck. Maybe your hard drive is dying? The system isn't installed to the hard drive in a live session, so a dying hard drive would be consistent with your account.

Comment: Try this. Boot from a live USB, and run the command `fsck -yf /dev/sdaX`, where `/sdaX`  is the address of home and the root partition (do for both of them separately). I had a similar error in an installed system which was forcefully shut down, and I was able to fix with these commands.

Comment: For what it's worth...  Just because the Live CD runs smoothly doesn't mean the hardware is fine.  Many parts of your system are "tested" with a Live CD, but not the hard disk...  Since it's a new system with presumably no data, you can also give Ubuntu itself a try and see if it installs.

Comment: Archisman, tried your fsck cmnd, didnt work either.

A faulty HD is a possibility, i think i will use a new hd and thats it.
I had the same issue 2 yrs ago, and a fresh reinstallation fixed the problem.